# How set encoding UTF-8 and the xmlns attribute in Symfony XmlEncoder

Tags: xml, symfony, xmlserializer, serialization

I use Symfony 3 Serializer and convert my objects to XML through XmlEncoder. But XmlEncoder don't have encoding type in xml prolog. How to solve this problem?

Can I add custom attribut with parameters after root element?

Is there any way to set xmlns in root element?

I need such XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<realty-feed xmlns="http://webmaster.yandex.ru/schemas/feed/realty/2010-06">
<generation-date>2010-10-05T16:36:00+04:00</generation-date> 
...
</realty-feed>
```

Now I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<realty-feed>
...
</realty-feed>
```

My serializer code fragment:

```
$xmlEncoder = new XmlEncoder('realty-feed');
$normalizer = new CustomNormalizer();
$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer),array($xmlEncoder));
$output = $serializer->serialize($objectData, 'xml');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. 
I created my own class and write the same methods as in default class XmlEncoder with some changes in few standart public and private methods.

```
    class N1XmlEncoder extends SerializerAwareEncoder implements EncoderInterface, DecoderInterface, NormalizationAwareInterface
    {
        ...

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function encode($data, $format, array $context = array())
        {
            if ($data instanceof \DOMDocument) {
                return $data->saveXML();
            }

            $xmlRootNodeName = $this->resolveXmlRootName($context);

            $this->dom = $this->createDomDocument($context);
            $this->format = $format;
            $this->context = $context;

            if (null !== $data && !is_scalar($data)) {
                $root = $this->dom->createElementNS('http://webmaster.yandex.ru/schemas/feed/realty/2010-06', $xmlRootNodeName);
                $dateTime = new \DateTime('now');
                $dateTimeStr = $dateTime->format(DATE_ATOM);
                $rootDate = $this->dom->createElement('generation-date', $dateTimeStr);
                $this->dom->appendChild($root);
                $root->appendChild($rootDate);
                $this->buildXml($root, $data, $xmlRootNodeName);
            } else {
                $this->appendNode($this->dom, $data, $xmlRootNodeName);
            }

            return $this->dom->saveXML();
        }
...
private function createDomDocument(array $context)
    {
        $document = new \DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');

        // Set an attribute on the DOM document specifying, as part of the XML declaration,
        $xmlOptions = array(
            // nicely formats output with indentation and extra space
            'xml_format_output' => 'formatOutput',
            // the version number of the document
            'xml_version' => 'xmlVersion',
            // the encoding of the document
            'xml_encoding' => 'encoding',
            // whether the document is standalone
            'xml_standalone' => 'xmlStandalone',
        );
        foreach ($xmlOptions as $xmlOption => $documentProperty) {
            if (isset($context[$xmlOption])) {
                $document->$documentProperty = $context[$xmlOption];
            }
        }

        return $document;
    }
```

Comment: and how you set "xmlns="http://webmaster.yandex.ru/schemas/feed/realty/2010-06"" context?

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$xmlEncoder = new XmlEncoder('realty-feed');
$xml = $xmlEncoder->encode([
    '@xmlns'          => 'http://webmaster.yandex.ru/schemas/feed/realty/2010-06',
    'generation-date' => '2010-10-05T16:36:00+04:00',
], 'xml');
echo $xml;
```

Comment: This works, but what if you need to nest multiple nodes with the same name under the root?

Comment: Can you please put XML example?

Comment: In my case what I needed was XML like this: 
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shares xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Share>
     <.../>
  </Share>
  <Share>
     <.../>
  </Share>
</shares>```

Comment: `$xmlEncoder = new XmlEncoder('shares');
$xml = $xmlEncoder->encode([
    '@xmlns:xsi' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
    'Share' => [
        '...',
        '...',
    ],
], 'xml');`

Comment: Ah very cool, that's much cleaner than what I suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

First create XmlEncoder with root node name (in your case it would be "realty-feed"):

```
$encoder = new XmlEncoder("realty-feed");
```

Than generate Xml file:

```
$xml = $encoder->encode([], 'xml', ['xml_encoding' => 'utf-8']);
```

Where **first** argument:
- array with your xml structure and data

**Second**:
- format

**Third**:
- context properties (in your case xml_enxoding)

**UPD**:

Method for setting attributes to xls root element. Work perfectly. !Take into consideration return type hinting (its only for PHP 7+)

```
/**
 * Add params to xml root element
 *
 * @param $xml
 * @return SimpleXMLElement
 */
private function setXmlParams(SimpleXMLElement $xml): SimpleXMLElement
{
    $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $xml->addAttribute('xmlns:xmlns:xsi', "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    $xml->addAttribute('xmlns:xmlns:xsd', "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    $xml->addAttribute('xmlns', "http://localhost/example");

    return $xml;
}
```

Output root element:

```
<Root 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns="http://localhost/example"
>
```

Comment: This does not allow for adding custom attributes like the OP asked for.

Comment: You can add any attribute separated by a comma

Comment: You mean like this?
    $encoder = new XmlEncoder('realty-feed');
    $xml = $encoder->encode([], 'xml', [
        'xml_encoding' => 'utf-8',
        'xmlns' => 'http://webmaster.yandex.ru/schemas/feed/realty/2010-06'
    ]);
Unfortunately that just returns <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><realty-feed/>. The extra attribute is ignored.

XmlEncoder looks for 4 specific keys in context (xml_format_output, xml_version, xml_encoding and xml_standalone). Everything else is ignored.

This is definitely the cleanest way if you just want to add the encoding though.

Answer (score 0):

On `{"symfony/serializer": "^5.0"}` version I was able to add those attributes in the following way:

```
$encoder = new XmlEncoder();
$nodes = ['@xmlns' => 'http://webmaster.yandex.ru/schemas/feed/realty/2010-06',
          'generation-date' => '2010-10-05T16:36:00+04:00'];
$xmlString = $encoder->encode($nodes, 'xml', [
    XmlEncoder::ROOT_NODE_NAME => 'realty-feed',
    XmlEncoder::ENCODING       => 'UTF-8',
]); 
echo $xmlString;
```

Also tried the following way which did NOT work:

```
$encoder = new XmlEncoder([
XmlEncoder::ROOT_NODE_NAME => $rootNodeName,
XmlEncoder::ENCODING       => $encoding,
'@xmlns' => 'http://webmaster.yandex.ru/schemas/feed/realty/2010-06',
]);

echo $encoder->encode($nodes, 'xml');
```